# #Error when using SUM(IIF( in one Report but not the other?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, expression, rdl

I am having a SUM(IIF( issue with my AR report where it is producing #ERROR and an incorrect aggregate of my data. What I want to do is have the Report calculate my Amounts across the rows and then give me a simple Grand Total with the Aging Grand Totals included.

When I click "Add Totals" to my Amount column, I receive the correct $ amount. The 4 proceeding rows are AR Aging expressions:

```
=SUM(iif(DateDiff("d",Fields!DateDue.Value, now())>=1 and DateDiff("d",Fields!DateDue.Value,Now())<=30,Fields!Amount.value,0))

=SUM(CDbl(iif(DateDiff("d",Fields!DateDue.Value, now())>=31 and DateDiff("d",Fields!DateDue.Value,Now())<=60,Fields!Amount.value,0)))
```

and so on and so forth...
For one of my reports, this Aging equation is working fine (same data set and data). For this one, I receive incorrect numbers and #Errors even though the data is the same.

As you see below my 61-90 days Column with ~$600 and $400 gives me a GT of $50k which is incorrect. The image below (trust me that all other rows are $0.00) represents this.

Any ideas why this could be happening behind the report? The data is validated; it does not appear to be a DB/Data issue.

[image] I am guessing it is a rookie grouping issue?
Any advice is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Did you check if there are null values for `Amount` or `DateDue` fields?

Comment: Yes, there are no NULL values in Amount/DateDue/GrossAmount being shown in the data

Comment: What is the field SouceBUI that you are grouping by? Note your aggregations are affected by grouping settings.

Comment: SourceBU is the "Company" here. So they are 5digit IDs. When I run my report, I get, for example:

10000, 10001, 10002, 10003, etc etc. with Amounts in their rows and then a Grand Total that Sums their amounts. My issue lies in the Aging columns. I am using those IIF statements for Aging, but if I put SUM(IIF(.. the aggregates are thrown off and I get #Error for them. 

http://imgur.com/c8ms2wY  First column represents the summed Amount which is correct. The other 4 are adding incorrect/#error-ing out

Comment: What is the expression you used in the company column?

Comment: =Fields!SourceBU.Value & " - " & Fields!PropName.Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue:

My Sums/Aggregate was OUTSIDE of the the row group SOURCE BU.

Therefore, I needed to add columns to the left, INSIDE the grouping so that my totals would match for each company.